# Swift Instance member cannot be used on type

Tags: swift

I defined a variable in super class and trying to refer it in subclass but getting error on Instance member cannot be used on type

```
class supClass: UIView {
    let defaultFontSize: CGFloat = 12.0
}

class subClass: supClass {

    private func calcSomething(font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(defaultFontSize)) {
        //... Do something
    }
}
```

What's wrong with it? thank you so much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default value of a method parameter is evaluated on class scope,
not instance scope, as one can see in the following example:

```
class MyClass {

    static var foo = "static foo"
    var foo = "instance foo"

    func calcSomething(x: String = foo) {
        print("x =", x)
    }
} 

let obj = MyClass()
obj.calcSomething() // x = static foo
```

and it would not compile without the `static var foo`.

Applied to your case it means that you have to make the property which is used
as the default value static:

```
class supClass: UIView {
    static let defaultFontSize: CGFloat = 12.0 // <--- add `static` here
}

class subClass: supClass {

    private func calcSomething(font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(defaultFontSize)) {
        //... Do something
    }
}
```

(Note that it is irrelevant for this problem whether the property is defined in the
same class or in a super class.)

Answer (score 9):

Problem is that you never initialized class anywhere so you cannot access the members of a non existing object (correct me if I'm wrong). Adding `static` will do the trick:

```
class supClass: UIView {
    static let defaultFontSize: CGFloat = 12.0
}
```