# Realm Swift: instance member cannot be used on type

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am getting this error:

> "Realm Swift: instance member 'Int' cannot be used on type 'Comment'"

[image]

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738252/swift-instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type) that suggest to use the keyword **static**. However, as the point of the function that I am writing is to access the primary key after that the object has been created, having a static variable would not work.

Any suggestion on how to improve this?

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Comment: Object {
    dynamic var id : Int = -1 

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return String(id)
    }
}
```

Comment: primaryKey function should return the variable name of primary key variable, not the value, so u should return "id" instead Ref: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise that.. now I see.. Realm accepts plain strings as way to refer to the internal variables.. nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting "@Octaviano Putra" in the comments this worked for me:

> primaryKey function should return the variable name of primary key
>   variable, not the value, so u should return "id" instead Ref:
>   [realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys)

Answer (score 0):

#### Type methods cannot directly access instance properties

I'll add this answer to explain the telling error message [**emphasis** mine]:

> "Realm Swift: **instance member** '`Int`' cannot be used **on type** '`Comment`'"

A *type* method cannot access *instance members* of the type without having explicit access to an *instance of the type itself* (which it does not, in you example above).

From [the Language Guide - Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html):

> **Type Methods**
>
> Instance methods, as described above, are methods that **are called on
>   an instance of a particular type**. You can also define methods that
>   **are called on the type itself**. These kinds of methods are called type methods. You indicate type methods by writing the `static`
>   keyword before the method’s `func` keyword. Classes may also use the
>   `class` keyword to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s
>   implementation of that method.

```
class Foo {
    // this is an _instance_ property, accessible to
    // _instances_ of the _type_ 'Foo'
    let instanceProperty: Int

    // this is a _type method_, owned by the _type_ 'Foo'
    class func typeMethod() -> String {
        // this method knows nothing about the _content_ of
        // particular instances of of the type itself (unless
        // we explictly provide this information to the method)
        return "foo"
    }
}
```